# how to set image name/tag for container images specified in CRDs in kustomization.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

how to set image name/tag for container images specified in CRDs through the `kustomization.yaml` using the images field?

The [images](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/images/) field works well when the container images are specified in either `Deployment` or `StatefulSet`, but not transform a CRD resource from:

```
apiVersion: foo.example.com/v1alpha1
kind: Application
spec:
  image: xxx
```

To:

```
apiVersion: foo.example.com/v1alpha1
kind: Application
spec:
  image: new-image:tag
```

Comment: A similar question has been asked here with the answer by using ImageTagTransformer: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/3542

Answer (score 4):

Your task can be solved easily using `yq`. The command depends on the `yq` implementation you are using:

#### [mikefarah/yq - version 4](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)

`IMAGE="new-image:tag" yq e '.spec.image = strenv(IMAGE)'`

#### [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)

`yq -y --arg IMAGE "new-image:tag" '.spec.image |= $IMAGE'`

Comment: Thank you! I believe it works by using `yq`. it would be great to include such solution as a kustomize plugin so that it can be done with YAML

Answer (score 3):

This is a working example of using the [ImageTagTransformer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/9a954d4f0b84c997ffcf13b926aa2389146ed2bc/docs/plugins/builtins.md#imagetagtransformer).

Given below yaml files:

```yaml
# transformer_1.yaml
---
apiVersion: builtin
kind: ImageTagTransformer
metadata:
  name: not-important-here
imageTag:
  name: xxx
  newName: new-image
  newTag: tag
fieldSpecs:
- path: spec/image
  kind: Application

# application.yaml
---
apiVersion: foo.example.com/v1alpha1
kind: Application
spec:
  image: xxx

# kustomization.yaml
---
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- application.yaml
transformers:
- transformer_1.yaml
```

Run this command:

```yaml
$ kustomize build ./ | kpt cfg grep "kind=Application"
apiVersion: foo.example.com/v1alpha1
kind: Application
spec:
  image: new-image:tag
```

However, I still need to figure out ways to get it work with skaffold workflow.

### Update

the [feedback](https://groups.google.com/g/skaffold-users/c/X4ex8vGhUMM) from skaffold community said it doesn't support rewriting manifests except those are in an [allowlist](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/blob/f280aa8325283a0f080989acef120c5597ebc4b7/pkg/skaffold/kubernetes/manifest/visitor.go#L28). So the lesson learn is, skaffold doesn't support rewriting any CRDs yet.